# Can “womenomics” be considered a neologism?

Tags: word-usage, dictionaries, neologisms, nonce-words

It is not the first time I come cross the term ***[womenomics](http://www.cnbc.com/id/101653699)*** used to refer to a wider presence of women in the economic activities of a country. In this case it refers to Japan, a country where women have traditionally little presence in the business and political life.

It seems that the term *womenomics* first appeared in 2009 as the title of a [book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Womenomics) which  deals with this issue extensively.   As of now in 2014, the term is absent from most dictionaries, and even in Google NGram there is not yet any evidence of it.

Can we consider *womenomics* a neologism?  Or if we cannot, then what standard of usage does a new word generally need to meet for it to be considered a neologism?

Comment: A neologism is simply a _newly coined word_, regardless of how standard it is considered or how much it is used. Since _womenomics_ is definitely not inherited from Old English, borrowed from some other language, or a word coined a long time ago, I'd say that makes it a neologism by default.

Comment: Is there a term for a coined word that hasn't really entered the general lexicon? A similar case would be "freakonomics", which was the title of a book and its authors' blog, but isn't really used much outside their context.

Comment: @Barmar most words are not really used much. Literally a hundred thousand in English alone. Nothing unusual. And for neologisms, the rate is of course much higher still. So having a term for that is like having a term for "a dog that is not purple" or "a skyscraper that has more than two stories". That'd be three words *more* that nobody ever uses.

Comment: This seems to be the kind of word I think of as a "marketing-ism". Like freakonomics, it's more about marketing the book or idea than for being used in standard or usual discourse. In this case, like many others, it also has a certain tint of laziness in that its meaning can be easily conveyed in standard word usage; women's participation in economics. Instead the author goes for building a new catchphrase, womenomics. Bah!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Polymath in the sense that *womenomics* does feel more like a phrase used by only a very small number of people and usually only in the context of that original book and its subject.  Its durability beyond that book has slumped to, as you say, the verge of non-existence.  Technically, it is a neologism, just one that has already run its race and been forgotten.

Comment: Perhaps then *nonce-word* is a better category for such one-time, flash-in-the-pan inventions than *neologism* is, in that the latter implies some degree of currency that the former does not.

Comment: Possibly, yes, but if the word is still in use, which it might be in certain circles, then it could be a neologism, just a not very well known one.

Comment: @tcrist. I like 'nonce-word'.